# Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights differ while training in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a net where I'm using two generators, one for training and one for validation. These are simply to functions that yield samples indefensibly.

I get the following error at the very end of the validation:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", 
line 1142, in average "Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights "
```

I looked into the code, the function `training_generator` in `keras.engine` contains the following line

```
averages.append(np.average([out[i] for out in outs_per_batch], weights=batch_sizes))
```

Looking at the definition of `np.average`, the function requires `axis` when weights and array are not the same length. I debugged the code, and by placing `axis=0` or `np.squeeze` over the `out[i]` it """"works"""", only to stop few lines after when it collects summary stats of the validation. I can't stop thinking that there is an error somewhere else in my code.

This is my generator

```
def batch_generator(batch_size, folder):
    files = listdir(folder)
    print("Folder " + folder + " with " + str(len(files)) + " files.")
    np.random.shuffle(files)
    while True:
        np.random.shuffle(files)
        for i in range(batch_size, len(files), batch_size):
            batch = files[(i-batch_size):(i)]
            batch = tensor_generator(folder, files=batch)
            yield (batch, batch)

def tensor_generator(folder, files=None):
    if files is None:
        files = listdir(folder)
    verbose = len(files)>100
    if verbose:
        pbar = tqdm(total=len(files), unit='img')
    tensor = []
    for f in files:
        f = SimpleITK.ReadImage(join(folder, f))
        f = SimpleITK.GetArrayFromImage(f)
        f = (f + 1000)/4000
        tensor.append(f)
        if verbose: pbar.update(1)
    if verbose: pbar.close()
    return np.stack(tensor, axis=0)
```

and this is the fit function

```
    self.autoencoder.fit_generator(
            generator=x_train,
            steps_per_epoch=iters,
            epochs=epochs,
            callbacks=[log, rop],
            validation_data=x_test,
            validation_steps=10)
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Do you happen to have any batch with size 0? What is your keras version and your tensorflow version?

Comment: Does the test generator really return 10 batches?

Comment: @DanielMöller no, the generator always returns a batch of size specified by the parameters. Keras 2.2 and tf 1.9

Comment: We expect that, but maybe a `for i in range(3*iters): print(next(x_train)[0].shape)` and a `for i in range(3*10): print(next(x_test)[0].shape)` could reveal something strange?

Comment: @DanielMöller let me check that right now

Comment: @DanielMöller BATCHSIZE x D1 x D2 x CHANNEL for all batches

Comment: Any custom metrics/loss?

Comment: @DanielMöller mse for the output, and KL as added loss in the latent representation.  The KL loss comes from the sample layer, you can find the code here https://github.com/shadySource/BVAE-tf/blob/master/bvae/model_utils.py

Comment: As far as I can tell your layer is outputting something with a different shape than that which the downstream keras infrastructure expects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. Even though i don' know what account for this issue, i have resolved this odd problem.

You only need to change your code `validation_data=x_test` to `validation_data=next(x_test)`. That means you only need add `next()` on your validation data generator.

Answer (score 0):

You need you to specify `None` in image spatial dimensions, e.g. `shape=(None,None,3)` for an RGB image.

BTW, it is not always feasible to use a pretrained model for predicting a testing image of a different size, e.g. a pretrained model containing `Dense` layers. However, it should be always possible for you to first resize a test image to the size used for training, and then predict on the resized version image.

Comment: Emmm I'm not using a pretrained network. Just that layer.

Answer (score 0):

the same problem happened to me, NA in weights also causes this problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).